# Is there a path for the script indicated on the Python-invocation command line?

Tags: python, windows, path

I want to invoke a Python script from a DOS shell command line (or from a .bat file) with a syntax like this:

```
C:\python27\python myscript.py
```

The script, `myscript.py` is located in a directory, `c:\a_process\python_lib`.  I would to be able to have Python find that script by searching a path, so I can invoke it when my current directory is arbitrary (like `C:\junk`).  My problem is that I can't find out what (if any) path Python uses for a script that is indicated on the Python-invoking command line.  I've searched the Python documentation, SO, and the web and really haven't found anything instructive.  (I found lots of stuff about command line parsing within Python itself, which isn't what I'm looking for).

I have a `adt_python_lib.pth` file in the `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` directory and verified that it works (I can import modules located there.)  As an experiment I have tried to also set `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable (verified by typing `SET` in the DOS shell and seeing the line

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\a_process\python_lib
```

in the output.  For what it is worth, I also invoked Python and did a `sys.path`, and I can see that indeed `C:\a_process\python_lib` is listed in the path as expected: `['', 'c:\\a_process\\python_lib', ...]`

The closest SO question I've found to this is [Executing python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461054/executing-python-program/10461185#10461185).

This seems to imply (but does not state) that there is no path that is searched for a file indicated on the Python-invocation command line.  If someone can authoritatively state that this is correct, then I'll revert to another alternative (probably just add `c:\a_process\python_lib` to `%PATH%` and invoke the script directly).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not seeing any change in behavior. I made sure there are no blanks after the semicolon in the PATH and I've tried with and without a trailing semicolon (another SO thread cautioned about these).  I can tell I've added to PATH correctly, since now typing myscript.py on the DOS command line does invoke the script (which is the "another alternative" I'll revert to if all else fails.)  What I was hoping for was a solution similar to using a .pth file which should be easier for us to distribute (no registry settings, etc.)

Comment: I always thought PYTHONPATH would cover this, but evidently it only applies to `import` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying the full file name, just specify the module with a `-m` switch.

```
C:\python27\python -m myscript
```

This assumes the directory is part of your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: That does work!  Thanks.  The problem I had before was that I included the .py extension.  Omitting the extension solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do exactly what you want, but...

Try wrapping up your Python command in a `.bat` and put the BAT file somewhere in your `PATH`. Then you can call the `.bat` from anywhere (just make sure to use only absolute paths in specifying the location of the python script to run in your BAT file).